# HTML/CSS - Using Custom Fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to use a custom font from: https://www.google.com/fonts/#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Underdog

I find the font is displaying correctly when I use a Nexus One Emulator in Eclipse but on my Samsung Galaxy S2 it doesn't work...

My code is as follows:

CSS:

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'Underdog', cursive;
}

#categories
{   
font-family: 'Underdog';
}

#subCategories
{
font-family: 'Underdog';
}

body
{
background-color:#272714;
}
```

HTML:

The drop down boxes are created dynamically with JQuery. The "loadingDiv" are shown and then hidden after an AJAX call is completed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>  

    <title>Coupon Finder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Underdog' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/storecategories.js"></script>

    <script> 

        function categorySubmit(){
            var selectedCategory = document.getElementById("category");
            var selectedText = $('#category option:selected').text();

            //Get Sub-Categories
            getSubCategories(selectedText);
        }


    </script>

</head>

<body >
    <div id='categories'>
        <h3>Coupon Categories</h3>
        <div id='loadingDiv'>
            Please wait...  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" />
        </div> 
     </div>

    <!--Add Category Search Button-->
    <button class = "buttons" onclick="categorySubmit()">Search!</button>


    <div id='subCategories'>            
        <div id='loadingDiv1'>
            Please wait...  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" />
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a screenshot of the output on the emulator (Sorry for the dark background... need to change that):

[image]

Any ideas why it isn't working on my Galaxy S2?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to do some remote debugging.

Check this out:

[How to do remote debugging on android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)

From there, you can use the console to see what happens in your code. 
You might even find that your S2 throws an error to the console.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I can't seem to install the ADB extension on my Laptop... =/